# Is it fine to assume "yum check-update" will be accurate when run without root?

Tags: yum

Is it fine to assume "yum check-update" will be accurate when run without root? People suggest against running "yum makecache" and say that other yum commands will update the cache. When I look up info about the cache I found [something](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-working_with_yum_cache) that even says it's off by default... So because the right way to run "yum check-update" is to just run it, if I'm running as a non-root user it will do something to update the cache, or tell me if it's out of date, or something right?

In the debian world I don't think this would be true. If I want up to date information something has to run "apt update". There are scripts that periodically sync this information so it can tell you when stuff is out of date but those run as root and in some environments like docker images you need to run "apt update" anyway.

If the answer is yes how does it work? Is there a setuid file that allows a nonroot user to work with a refreshed cache or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yum cannot download and parse the data if it doesn't have a place to
write the data out to. When run as not root, it can't
write to `/var/cache/yum`.
A non-root user can't modify the metadata in this root-owned location.

Running "yum check-update" as non-root may fail or may give wrong
answers, if the cache hasn't been updated, which sort of defeats the
purpose.